# generating R.JAVA files manually using aapt2

Tags: java, android, bash, command-line, apk

I need to build `R.JAVA` files by using command line `aapt2`, is there any ways or codes to generate R.JAVA files by using `aapt2` command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2#link), aapt2 can generate an `R.java` file during the `link` phase.  The general syntax is:

```
aapt2 link path-to-input-files [options] -o
        outputdirectory/outputfilename.apk --manifest AndroidManifest.xml
```

There are options that change the way the `R.java` file is generated and where it is written.